# How can I specify window frame for my sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How/Can I specify this window frame:

```sql
sum(Quantity) over (partition by AccountId, SymbolId order by Time rows between unbounded preceding and current row -1) PositionAmount?
```

I tried to full it by

```sql
sum(Quantity) over (partition by AccountId, SymbolId order by Time rows between unbounded preceding and -1 following)
```

but -1 is not allowed.

I can of course make a second select over it and find prev value of PositionAmount with lag or something.

Comment: It's `1 PRECEDING`. [ROWS or RANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#rows-or-range)

Answer (score 2):

The [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) specifies, in case you use `between`, that both parts are `window frame bound`, without forcing you to use `following` for the second part. Try this:

`rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding`